# Hot Corners in Monterey are too "hot" - very easily triggered

Tags: macos, terminal, ui, monterey

For almost as long as I've been a Mac user, I have used a Hot Corner to trigger my display to go to sleep, which in effect locks my machine, because a password is needed to get back into the OS.

The problem is that since updating to Monterey, the approx. 1 second delay is gone, so if my cursor so much as touches the corner I need to re-enter my password. It's becoming really annoying.

Is there a way to get that short delay back (maybe using a Terminal command)?

Comment: I’m on Big Sur and hot corners are hot.

Comment: I add Ctrl to the corners which prevents accidental triggering.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for contributing that detail. I went from Mojave straight to Monterey, so that's why I'm noticing this change for the first time in Monterey. Maybe a Catalina user can take the temperature of their corners to help us know in which version these things became too hot to handle.

Comment: @Tetsujin How do you do this? I don't see an option for requiring a modifier key.

Comment: It's a bit non-standard. You just open the drop-menu, select which line you need, then hold whatever modifier[s] you want, then let go - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qobKM.gif

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you! Non-standard indeed! I can only recall ever having seen something similar in [Keyboard Viewer](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/12395029). Would you care to post as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get around the accidental corner-hit by adding  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  to each corner.

The implementation is a bit non-standard.
Open the drop menu, select your option, then hold one or more modifier keys & you'll see they add to the item. Once you've chosen the key, click [or release] your selection.

[image]

Gif set to not loop, or it gets a bit confusing. Click to open it.